# How to find the time difference with dayjs in cypress?

Tags: javascript, cypress, dayjs

I'm trying to find the time taken for an element to load using this code but doesn't work.

Expected Result: Total time taken is 90 seconds(or in milliseconds)

```
const start = cy.log(dayjs.format("HH:mm.ss.SSS));
const end = cy.log(dayjs.format("HH:mm.ss.SSS));

const diff = dayjs(end).unix() - dayjs(start).unix();
const timetaken = dayjs.utc(diff).format("HH.mm.ss.SSS");

cy.log(timetaken);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gets a bit tricky because Cypress runs things in a command queue, you need to run (most) dayjs commands in `.then()` callbacks.

Here's a simple example

```js
import dayjs from 'dayjs'

const duration = require('dayjs/plugin/duration')
dayjs.extend(duration)

it('times loading a site and selecting an element', () => {

  const start = dayjs();
  let end;

  cy.visit('http://example.com')
  cy.get('h1').then(() => {    
    // ensure end is set only after get command finishes
    // by using a .then()

    end = dayjs();   
    cy.log(`start: ${start.format("HH:mm.ss.SSS")}`)
    cy.log(`end: ${end.format("HH:mm.ss.SSS")}`)
    cy.log(`diff: ${dayjs.duration(end.diff(start)).$ms} ms` )
  })
})
```

If you want to do some more testing steps before diffing, you can use Cypress aliases to keep a hold of the start and end.

```js
import dayjs from 'dayjs'

const duration = require('dayjs/plugin/duration')
dayjs.extend(duration)

it('times loading a site using aliases', () => {

  cy.wrap(dayjs()).as('start')

  cy.visit('http://example.com')
  cy.get('h1').then(() => {
    cy.wrap(dayjs()).as('end');    // must wrap "end" inside a .then()!
  })

  // other test stuff here

  cy.get('@start').then(start => {
    cy.get('@end').then(end => {
      cy.log(`start: ${start.format("HH:mm.ss.SSS")}`)
      cy.log(`end: ${end.format("HH:mm.ss.SSS")}`)
      cy.log(`diff: ${dayjs.duration(end.diff(start)).$ms} ms` )
    })
  })

})
```